# Storing files in arrays and vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, database, file, vector

I have been trying to figure out how to store strings and doubles from a txt file in arrays and vectors but i just cant get it in my head. I did quite a lot of research and didnt find something that explained it to me. Basically my task is to read from a file that contains username password and a number like money or points in this format. 
Enis tah \n
MyPassw0rd1$$4 \n
436.18 \n

Enis1 tAh \n
mYpassWord \n
76.2 \n

the \ is not in the txt file but the name pass and number are in different lines not same line of the text

....

For the files i know the size i can use arrays for the ones i dont know the size i can use vectors. Then ask the user to input username and password if it maches it lets the user login and allowes him to access the bank account or see the points.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


void mainMenu();

using namespace std;




 int main(){

 ifstream storeFromFile("student_info.txt");

 vector<string> Usernames;
 string getUsernames;
 while (!storeFromFile.eof()) {
    cin.ignore();
    getline(storeFromFile, getUsernames);




  }
for (int i=0; i<=Usernames.size(); i++) {

Usernames.push_back(getUsernames);
cout << Usernames[0];
 }
 mainMenu();


 return 0;
 }



 void mainMenu(){
 cout <<"\n[DA] to view all grades" <<endl;
 cout <<"[T] to view top x students" <<endl;
 cout <<"[P] to view one grade in particular" <<endl;
 cout <<"[E] to exit\n" <<endl;
 }
```

Comment: Please search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ read file separated".  There already a plethora of similar questions.

Comment: I know how to read from a file but i dont understand how to store them in arrays and vectors so i can use them o comapre with user input.

Comment: Arrays and vectors have equivalent syntax for storing elements: `a[index] = value;`  You should research your favorite reference for vector, or search the internet for "c++ vector example".

Answer (score 0):

You really want to model each record using a `class` or `struct`.

Define a class with one member for each "column" or field in the record (line of text).

Overload the extraction operator, `operator >>`, for your class to input each member from the stream.

Declare a container of these classes as your database, e.g. `std::vector<Record> database;`.

Change your input loop to:

```
Record r;
while (data_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

That's the essence for reading in a CSV file (even though your file uses other delimiters than a comma).

Comment: is there a way to do it without using struct or class because im not allowed to use them. if you can explain it to me id really appreciate it im trying my best but i just do not understand it so if you can kinda walk me through it that would be awesome. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with "parallel" vectors or arrays.  Research them in your favorite reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use struct and define the structure of the document. And then read it line by line. This link could help . https://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Serialize-Your-Class-into-Streams-in-C/

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

```
const int sizeLimit = 50;
string firstName[sizeLimit], lastName[sizeLimit], passWord[sizeLimit];
double accountBalance[sizeLimit];
int count = 0;

ifstream readFile("Accounts.txt");

while (!readFile.eof())
{
    readFile >> firstName[count];
    readFile >> lastName[count];
    readFile >> passWord[count];
    readFile >> accountBalance[count];
    count++;
}
```